# Which are the strongest and most durable materials?

Tags: filament, material

I am working on a robotics project and need to print some gears. These will probably by under a LOT of pressure. Which material/filament should I choose so that the gears don't wear off easily?

PS: Newbie here...

**EDIT:**
According to my instuctor, it has to be some sort of plastic (not metal).
It also has to be lightweight...

Comment: What kind of printer are you using?

Comment: This question seems primarily opinion-based to me. However, maybe it would be a good question if we made it more specific. Given a few numbers on the expected pressure, and then ask if specific materials can fit the requirement.

Comment: 'Newbie here'? Just saying, this site is hardly a day old :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as you say you want to materials for printing robotics parts. And as you have not given any budget constraint, I would give you a list of materials which would help you achieve the task, and you can choose amongst them accordingly.

1. Plastics: Basically used for building prototypes. Nylon Polyamide should be a choice for you.

> Polyamide 3D printing is achieved through SLS 3D printing. It offers
>   strong and flexible prints. The upside of this material is that the
>   printing technology requires minimum preparation of the 3D file before
>   printing. There is no need for support. And it also offers the
>   possibility to create intricate shapes and moving part in just one go.
>   After the print the polyamide can be polished and dyed.

2. Metals: Metals like Brass, Alumunium and Steel should be a good choice.

But, if I were to achieve your task, I would select carbon fiber. some details about it:

> Carbon fiber consists of 90% carbon atoms, each fiber is 10 times
>   thinner than a human hair. Carbon is especially prized for its lack of
>   combustibility and infusability but also by its incredible strength
>   (stronger than steel) and ability to create flexible structure, light
>   weight and corrosion resistance. Its melting temperature is 1500, this
>   heat there are only carbon.

Comment: Yeah... I think carbon fiber might be able to do the job... Thanks!

Comment: You can upvote the answer if it helped you, and wait for more answers before you make a choice to accept :)

Comment: The segment you quoted applies to pure carbon fiber, but not to carbon fiber *filled* filament. The parts won't necessarily be stronger (especially in terms of layer bonding) than the plastic resin in which the carbon fiber is only a filler.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden Interesting!  What is your take on carbonfiber vs Nylon?   Well, that is sad. Carbon Fiber is meant to be stronger than plastic-based materials, right?

Comment: @Dawny33 going to buy a 3d printer tomorrow cuz our old one is spoilt... any recommendations?

Comment: @RahulBasu Can't recommend unless you tell us what specs, budget, etc.  And this would make a nice question in the HardwareRecommendations SE :)

Comment: @Dawny33 ooohhhh, that's a site? Anyways, budget is USD850, and I have no idea about specs...

Answer (score 1):

Filaments that are intended for making parts that require strange should be rated by the manufacturer for strength and flexibility.

You need to calculate the required strength and then choose a material with higher rating

For example the rating for filaments made by Taulman are at http://www.taulman3d.com/how-to-choose.html?m